# why Cmake's " file(REMOVE_RECURSE [file1 ...]) "does not remove file having *.xxx.yy extension file?

Tags: cmake

I want to remove all the files from my binary directory which has ".asm.js" extension
below is my source code

```
file (REMOVE
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/*.asm.js
    )
```

Unfortunately, It's not able to delete the file which has .asm.js extension.
is there anyone who can help me with this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to delete all the "asm.js" type of files in the subdirectory as well then you can use the below command

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_FILES  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/**/*.asm.js)
```

Answer (score 4):

As CMake docs says :

> Remove the given files. The REMOVE_RECURSE mode will remove the given
>   files and directories, also non-empty directories. No error is emitted
>   if a given file does not exist.

So you need to do a list of files to send it to `file(REMOVE)`

To do it you can use :

`file(GLOB MY_FILES  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/*.asm.js)`

Or if you want to match them in subdirectories :

`file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_FILES  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/*.asm.js)`

Then you can use your command :

`file (REMOVE
    ${MY_FILES}
)`

Comment: file (REMOVE
    ${MY_FILES}
)
this syntex is not valid , Cmake complain about it .
2>CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (file):
2>  file must be called with at least two arguments.

Comment: You need to put `""` around `${MY_FILES}` so that if the list is empty it will works too.